# what does define $a^x$ for any $a \in \Bbb R$ and $x \in \Bbb Z$ mean?

Tags: exponentiation

wikipedia says for positive integer exponents its defined by the initial condition

$b^1=b$ and the recurrence relation $b^{n+1} = b^n*b$ and for negative integers its defined as $a^{-n}=\frac{1}{a^n}$.

so is this definition of $a^x$ for all integers, as you are clearly describing the nature of this notation for all integer $x$, but $0$?

also is $a^{-n}=\frac{1}{a^n}$ like an axiom as its just taken to be true or can you prove it. Thanks (hopefully this is clearer than my earlier question)

Comment: [Defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Integer_exponents) means ... defined.

Comment: You may have seen, in many math classes and math textbooks, that lecturers and textbook authors define things. Now it's your turn!

Comment: If we agree with the basic definitions and the proof of the property that $a^{n+m}=a^na^m$ we have that $a^na^{−n}=a^{n−n}=a^0=1$.Thus, form $a^na^{−n}=1$ we have that $a^{−n}=\dfrac {1}{a^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply $$b^0=1$$
$$b^{n+1}=b(b^n)$$
$$b^{-n}=\frac{1}{b^n}$$
In terms of proving your last statement, consider that $\frac{b^n}{b^n}=1=b^0$ and $b^xb^y=b^{x+y}$. Then $x+y=0 \iff y=-x$ and you can establish that $b^{-n}=\frac{1}{b^n}$

Comment: So ... have we defined $0^{-1}$ here?

Comment: I am simply working off the constraints the OP presented, which are $a \in \Bbb R$, $a\ne 0$ and $x \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: so you proved the bottom identity using the first two, but where did they come from?

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to understand how to prove anything i would like to know in a general sense: a^x has no meaning until you define it so i believe you done that with your first two statements for 0,1,2.... But my question is where did this definition come from?

Comment: It's not accurate to say that "$a^x$ has no meaning until you define it". In fact, it has exactly the intuitive meaning that it had when you first encountered it in school: "$a^x$ means $a$ multiplied by itself $x$ times". But the mathematician's job is to express this not in an English sentence but instead as a rigorous mathematical definition.

Comment: @JamesDoherty $b^n=\underbrace{b\cdot b\cdot b\cdot ... \cdot b}_{n\text{times}}$. It then follows that $b^n=\frac 1b(b^{n+1})$, and taking $b=0$, we get that $b^0=\frac{b}{b}=1$.

Comment: Thanks but does that definition you have given for b^n only hold for positive integers? have they not defined b^0 as 1 so that the properties fit?

Comment: Based off my product, it's not immediately clear that $b^0=1$, so I used the product to show that it is.

Comment: is the correct way to think about this function not in parts. b^0=1 is just a definition and this is used in the recurrence relation a^(x+1)=a^x*a^1 to define the function for all integers non negative. Then you have to define what the function means for negative indices as well using the third equation?